# Promise.allSettled un-documented behaviour?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

Why does `Promise.allSettled` not consider the 3rd `Promise.resolve(10)`?

```js
const promises =[];
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(_=>{promises.push(Promise.resolve(10));resolve(1)}, 100, 'foo'));
promises.push(promise1)
promises.push(promise2)

Promise.allSettled(promises).
  then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.value)));
```

I am not looking for answers to solve this, I need documentation or explanation link stating this to be as is coded.

My assumption was it iterates one element at a time which will always take the full array into account but it feels like it has a snapshot of array at that time.

Comment: Uh, seems to work exactly as intended. Nothing to do with `Promise.allSettled()` - you're just adding the third promise *after* handing over the promises to the method. I don't see why it would be "undocumented" that it would only take the two promises it was given initially. Seems quite intuitive. Otherwise `Promise.allSettled(promises).then(handleArray); promises[7] = someNewPromise;` would have quite hard to understand results.

Comment: Not that intuitive cause the way i think of the iterator as mentioned above is like it `settles` one item at a time which mean if the array is edited it should be able to see all elements.?

Comment: We are talking about `Promise.allSettled` and not `Promise.any` which can have the snapshot of array as its racing between elements?..

Comment: I struggle to think of anything in JS where you give it an array and acts on changes to the arrays in the mean time. "*i think of the iterator as mentioned above is like it settles one item at a time*" well, that would be completely wrong, then. It's not *iterating* through the array *at resolution*. That would be quite inconvenient to 1. implement 2. follow through as somebody who just uses it. `arr = [1, 2, 3]; Promise.allSettled(arr).then(printValues)` is thus allowed to print `8, 5, 3`. Which I think you'll agree seems *quite weird*. Now you have to track where is the array changed.

Comment: You are right nothing else in JS seems to works on mutation like Map, Foreach etc, but it kind of violates `pass by ref` ideology i feel, And it wont be that hard to implement element iteration a simple while loop can make the stuff work, my belief is and i can be wrong, the implementation seems to be shadow of Promise.any refactoring or implementation.. anyway i was interested in documentation link for this but seems like it may be covered under Array mutation with loops as indirect reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.allSettled` takes an array as argument and processes that array as it is *at that moment*.

Whether any future execution of code alters that array, by adding or removing elements from it, is of no relevance: it is at the moment you call `Promise.allSettled` that you tell the function *which* promise objects you want to take part in that "all".

As to your comments (both in question and comment section):

> My assumption was it iterates one element at a time

It iterates the array immediately, *synchronously*. `allSettled` returns immediately. All it has done is collect the promise objects from the given array, add `then` listeners to each of those, and return a promise object -- all immediately.

These listeners will execute later, in an undetermined order, and these will not look at the array, but at their own promise resolution and corresponding index in the result array.

> it feels like it has a snapshot of array at that time.

No, there is no snapshot. Once the function returns, the array is no longer of importance for the logic of `allSettled` which now has attached listeners to each of the promise objects: each accompanied by a unique index. Once all promises have settled, a result array can be delivered as resolution value for the promise that `allSettled` had returned. At no point during this asynchronous processing is the original array relevant. It plays no role in the asynchronous part.

> ...but it kind of violates *pass by ref* ideology I feel

JavaScript has no pass-by-reference. You probably mean that arrays are references (which are passed by value). And yes, it is true that the function sees the same array as the caller. But the function executes synchronously, so it will see the array as it is at the moment the function is called, and after that synchronous part, it has no more role to play. Secondly, the result array is a new array, and so it is unrelated to any prior reference.

Comment: Thanks that explains, Sync execution where only "then" method wriing is done.

Comment: Just a point on pass by ref i thought every non primitive datatype is pass by ref in JS and the reference is maintained even when mutation occurs right?

Comment: Pass-by-reference is a concept which means that an **assignment** to a parameter will affect the caller's variable. This is not the case in JavaScript. However, what is true, is that the memory that is *referenced* by the parameter can be mutated by the function. But that is not the principle of pass-by-reference. Real pass-by-reference is what `&` does in C++ parameters. That's a magic that JavaScript doesn't offer. In JavaScript it is pass by value, but the value can be a reference.

Comment: Oh its like pointer(ref) passed by value.. intresting, but as you said in the sync execution it wont even matter cause its not been mutated by that time so seems logical..